# Mostrar una gran cantidad de registros en un frame con php

Tags: php

Hola que tal amigos quisiera saber como puedo realizar lo siguiente: estoy haciendo una consulta mediante una lista desplegable, es decir en la lista guardo "nombres de empresas" por decir.

Seleccione la empresa:

-coca

-pepsi

-alpura

al seleccionar la empresa me despliega los datos personales de todos los trabajadores que laboran alli.

nombre - apellidop - apellidom

juan       perez        perez

pero al ser varios cientos se satura la pantalla. 
la cuestión es que es necesario que muestre los registros en la misma pantalla de inicio. entonces pensé en un iframe,

solo que no se la manera de desplegar los datos , solo el resultado  del select en la misma pantalla.

espero puedan ayudarme. gracias

Comment: por favor muestra que tienes hecho para que a la gente le resulte más fácil echarte una mano. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres hacer paginacion de contenido y deseas mostrar toda la informacion, es que coloques la consulta dentro de un DIV y a este le apliques una regla CSS para hacer un overflow vertical como este ejemplo:

```html
<style> 
div.ex1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>

<h2>overflow-y: scroll:</h2>
<div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</div>
```

Ajustas los valores de width y height al area visible que deseas mostrar.

Comment: una respuesta bastante ingeniosa y útil, muchas gracias, sin meterme en ajax ni nada realmente quería algo simple y me sirvió. Alexander